# iOS viewport issue: loading zoomed

Tags: ios, iphone, zooming, viewport

I need to set the viewport at 490px, non-scalable

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=490, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

With the iphone in portrait mode, pages are loading slightly zoomed. A double-tap zooms them back out to the appropriate 490px. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=490, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=1">
```